# Challenges configuring hibernate JNDI for tomcat

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, hibernate-mapping

Hi everyone, i have been trying to configure my application to use Hibernate ORM but am having challenges with the JNDI property specification as i am unable to specify the "hibernate.jndi.class" for tomcat, I keep getting an error when the application tries to configure hibernate (**"javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial"**).

I had like to know if anyone has been successful with the JNDI configuration on tomcat and if so i had like the person(s) to share the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Below i have posted my current hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory  name="HibernateSessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> 
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">inheritance</property> 
        
        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
    <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i will try to answer this as I had similar issue and also was having *NoInitialContextException* and I **removed  name attribute of session-factory**  like in your case

```
<session-factory  name="HibernateSessionFactory">
```

to just

```
<session-factory>
```

so hibernate creates its own SessionFacade and does not try to use the one of the JNDI.
But it may also require changes in DAO.

Comment: really appreciate your response Viraj Nalawade, but i tried removing the name attribute and the error was still the same. However you talked about changes in DAO, could you please explain. Thanks in advance

Comment: No if the exception does not change after removing name the DAO changes are useless